# IN Sub Statement in Zend Prepared Statement

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I am working on a project in which i need to use prepared statements to prevent sql injections. Although i find the syntax to be used for queries for update,delete and insert statements. but for select query Its not working for IN sub statement. 
I am trying to do as follows :

```
 $arr= 'tomwased,eshantsahu';
 $this->_db->fetchAll("select username,password from user where username in (?)",array($arr)));
```

but its not working.I am getting the string $arr from other code.

Comment: What is `$this->_db`.?

Comment: $DB is a database adapter. 
$DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($config["resources"]["db"]["params"]);
Zend_Registry::set('DB',$DB); // saved in registry
$this->_db = Zend_Registry::get('DB'); // retrived from registry in model

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr                   =   array('tomwased','eshantsahu');
$db                     =   Zend_Registry :: get('db');
$select                 =   $db->select(); 
$select                 ->  from("user",array('username','password'))
                       ->  where("username in ?",$arr); 
$stmt                   =   $db->query($select);
$result             =   $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use statement like below

```
$productIds = array(1, 2, 3);

$select = $db->select()
             ->from('products',
                    array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
             ->where('product_id IN (?)', $productIds);
```

And to convert as for user

```
$username = array('tomwased','eshantsahu');

$select = $db->select()
             ->from('user',
                    array('username', 'password '))
             ->where('username IN (?)', $username );
```

hopw this will sure work for you

Comment: this is all i have tried , but its not returning any data , it is just returning an empty array.

Comment: pls each $select and run this query to direct my sql.